# About a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb(C):|z|<1\}$. Let $f$ be analytic and an automorphism on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $|f(z)|=|z|$ for every $z\in\mathbb{D}$.
Then there exist a constant $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$ such that $f(z)=\alpha z$ for $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

Can anyone tell why $\alpha$ be a constant? Why can’t it vary with every $z$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to know $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb D.$ Let $U = \mathbb D\setminus \{0\}.$ Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $|f(z)/z| = 1$ for $z\in U.$ Then $f(z)/z$ maps the open connected set $U$ into the unit circle, which is not open in $\mathbb C.$ By the open mapping theorem, $f(z)/z$ is constant in $U.$ Clearly this constant has modulus $1.$ Thus $f(z) = \alpha z$ for $z\in U.$ This solves the given problem.